# Docker : Echo to Terminal used to run Docker Image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a way for echo's to show up in the terminal where the docker run command is issued. It appears echo's only show here if the -d option isn't used. I can do docker logs to see these echos but I wanted to know if there was a way for them to show directly in the terminal issuing the run command?

Dockerfile:

```
# Generic Docker Image for Running Node app from Git Repository
FROM    node:0.10.33-slim
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Add script to pull Node app from Git and run the app
COPY docker-node-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE  8080
CMD ["--help"]
```

Entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# Run the command passed in if it isn't to start a node app
if [ "$1" != 'node-server' ]; then
   exec "$@"
fi
# Logic for pulling the node app and starting it
cd /usr/src
# try to remove the repo if it already exists
rm -rf node-app; true
echo "Pulling Node app's source from $2"
git clone $2 node-app
cd node-app
# Check if we should be running a specific commit from the git repo
if [ ! -z "$3" ]; then
  echo "Changing to commit $3"
  git checkout $3
fi
npm install
echo "Starting the app"
exec node .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have either -d or stdout, but not both. If you want to run container in background with stdout you could use &

```
$ docker run ubuntu echo "Stdout from container" &
[1] 2751
$ Stdout from container
```

or you could use -d and docker logs -f